# Removing outliers that are skewing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, normalization, denormalization

I am looking at the relationship between agricultural intensity and functional diversity of birds.

In my GLM model I have included a number of other variables including forest, semi-natural habitat, temperature, pesticides etc.

When looking to see whether my variables are normally distributed or not, I used a QQplot to identify the normality and there appears to be these 3 outliers.

I wondered how I would remove these outliers to make my data more normally distributed?

I tried to use the outliers package but all the examples I found failed to work, or I failed to understand how they worked!

Any help would be appreciated. This is my QQ plot for my functional dispersion model and a scatter of functional dispersion x agricultural intensity.
QQ plot

[image: QQ plot]

functional dispersion x agriculture scatter

[image: functional dispersion x agriculture scatter]

Comment: Removing data points simply because they do not fit your model is a bad idea, also there is no normality assumption on the data for a linear model.

Comment: GLM assumes normal distribution of residuals, not the variables in the model. How would you scientifically justify the removal of certain variables just because they may not fit your model? What if your model is wrong? Is the current model "good enough"? Why?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the observations that appear out of place. Given the amount of observations, this is unlikely to change estimates, but please make sure this is indeed the case. Also, when reporting your work, make sure you justify why you removed those points based on your domain knowledge about the variable.

You can remove the observation using

```
model.data.scaled <- model.data.scaled[model.data.scaled$agri > -5, ]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this - it doesn't seem to have removed them, have i done something wrong?

`model.data.scaled.outlier <- model.data.scaled[model.data.scaled$agri > -5, ]

func.disp.glm.outlier <- glm(func_disp ~ (forest * fert_total) + fert_total + agri + transformed$diversity + transformed1$bio1, gaussian(link = "identity"),data=model.data.scaled.outlier) 


plot(func.disp.glm.outlier, which = 2)`

Comment: Please make sure that at least rows 970, 710 and 938 have been removed. Please use comments for text only, the code snippet you provide (especially the plotting part) shows no relevant information. Also I see you are using data from two different sources. This may not be ideal. Without a reproducible example this is probably the best I can give you.